# partial matching no vba

Tags: excel

Looking for a excel formula, that will partial match two Columns full of names(strings) with an adjustable amount Of characters that are considered a match. For example 4 or 5 of the same characters within a word is a match but I would like to adjust this formula. For example

Comment: Hi Micheal Piggott! Welcome to SO! You're question is a bit unclear - can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP is fantastic as long as you are looking for exact matches. The TRUE / FALSE argument doesn't really serve the purpose you'd thought it serves. When you're looking for things that are not so black and white, you'd need some fuzzy logic here.

A quick example of where VLOOKUP falls short :

- Song name A = "Beethoven : Fidelio op.72"
- Song name B = "Beethoven : Fidelio opus 72"

Microsoft released a free add in to Excel (compatible with most recent versions) that enables fuzzy vlook up'ing. Get the file (add-in + documentation + example) here :

> > http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

It exports by default the matching degree so you can play on a few parameters from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some functions. You can use a function such as Match and VLookup function

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)

MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you basically want a fuzzy vlookup, there is an add-in that provides this. The PowerUps add-in for Excel works in Excel 2003 thru 2013. It has a function called pwrVLOOKUP that does fuzzy vlookups and operates basically the same as vlookup, just fuzzy if you want. An example is posted on the page here: http://officepowerups.com/2013/10/23/fuzzy-vlookup-in-excel/.